# Passing ref through to hook issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I've written a simple hook to display a popper menu when a button is clicked, I'm having an issue passing the buttonRef, It seems to be passing it to the component however the element is not positioned correctly as if it isn't passed at all.

I've included an example on codeSanbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/9o03qx3n3o

I've confirmed this works when not inside the hook, React dev tools shows it's passing the same element in both instances. I've tried using forwardRef, same issue, I've tried using the standard state to store the ref to no avail;

```
--- Hook ---

const usePopperMenu = btnRef => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  const handleClose = event => {
    if (btnRef.current.contains(event.target)) {
      return;
    }
    setOpen(false);
  };
  const elems = ({ children }) => (
    <Popper
      open={open}
      anchorEl={btnRef.current}
      placement="bottom"
      transition
      disablePortal
    >
      {({ TransitionProps, placement }) => (
        <Grow
          {...TransitionProps}
          id="menu-list-grow"
          style={{
            transformOrigin:
              placement === "bottom" ? "center top" : "center bottom"
          }}
        >
          <Paper>
            <ClickAwayListener onClickAway={e => handleClose(e)}>
              <MenuList>{children}</MenuList>
            </ClickAwayListener>
          </Paper>
        </Grow>
      )}
    </Popper>
  );
  return [elems, setOpen, open];
};

--- App/Component ---

function App() {
  const btnRef = useRef(null);
  const [Menu, setOpen, open] = usePopperMenu(btnRef);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <Button
          buttonRef={btnRef}
          onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}
          variant="outlined"
          color="secondary"
        >
          Click Me!
        </Button>
        <Menu>
          <MenuItem>
            <Typography color="textPrimary">Menu Item 1</Typography>
          </MenuItem>
          <MenuItem>
            <Typography color="textPrimary">Menu Item 2</Typography>
          </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It works good for me - problem is with your css styles. Button container is full size and `display:grid` thats why dropdown is misplaced

Try:

```
.App {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/oprzyv665?fontsize=14

Answer (score 0):

The problem in you code is that, you run the hook and pass ref to it which isn't initially assigned to the button element. It will only be assigned after initial render and post that you do not re-render your app to re-initialise your hook so that it gets the correct ref. Also you are trying to fit in custom hook where you don't need them. What you are trying to achieve can simply be done using a component model.

Your Popper code will look like

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Grow from "@material-ui/core/Grow";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import Popper from "@material-ui/core/Popper";
import ClickAwayListener from "@material-ui/core/ClickAwayListener";
import MenuList from "@material-ui/core/MenuList";

const PopperMenu = ({ target, children, open, handleClose }) => (
  <Popper
    open={open}
    anchorEl={target.current}
    placement="bottom"
    transition
    disablePortal
  >
    {({ TransitionProps, placement }) => (
      <Grow
        {...TransitionProps}
        id="menu-list-grow"
        style={{
          transformOrigin:
            placement === "bottom" ? "center top" : "center bottom"
        }}
      >
        <Paper>
          <ClickAwayListener onClickAway={e => handleClose(e)}>
            <MenuList>{children}</MenuList>
          </ClickAwayListener>
        </Paper>
      </Grow>
    )}
  </Popper>
);

export default PopperMenu;
```

and you can use this like

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";
import PopperMenu from "./hooks";
import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const btnRef = useRef(null);
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const handleClose = event => {
    if (btnRef.current.contains(event.target)) {
      return;
    }
    setOpen(false);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <Button
          buttonRef={btnRef}
          onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}
          variant="outlined"
          color="secondary"
        >
          Click Me!
        </Button>
        <PopperMenu target={btnRef} handleClose={handleClose} open={open}>
          <MenuItem>
            <Typography color="textPrimary">Menu Item 1</Typography>
          </MenuItem>
          <MenuItem>
            <Typography color="textPrimary">Menu Item 2</Typography>
          </MenuItem>
        </PopperMenu>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

**[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/oook312oy9)**